# Pivoting in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have a MySQL table named switches as follows:

```
switchName  switchCondition switchingTime 
----------- --------------- ------------- 
First       ON              10:00      
First       OFF             11:00
Second      ON              10:30      
Third       OFF             13:00      
Third       ON              13:45
```

How can I display a report as html table in the following format using above table by pivoting the switching time with respect to switch condition?

```
switchName   ON     OFF 
----------- -----  -------
First       10:00   11:00                   
Second      10:30    -        
Third       13:45   13:00
```

Comment: is it possible to have 3rd or 4th entry of `First`?

Comment: Might be... @VishalZanzrukia and in that case I guess `MAX()` can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.switchName, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.switchCondition = 'ON' THEN s.switchingTime ELSE '-' END) AS SwitchON, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.switchCondition = 'OFF' THEN s.switchingTime ELSE '-' END) AS SwitchOFF
FROM switches s 
GROUP BY s.switchName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
SELECT s.switchName, s1.switchingTime, s2.switchingTime
FROM switches s
LEFT JOIN switches s1 ON s.switchName = s1.switchName AND s1.switchCondition = 'ON'
LEFT JOIN switches s2 ON s.switchName = s2.switchName AND s2.switchCondition = 'OFF'
GROUP BY s.switchName
```

(although it represents your dash as `NULL`)